# UITableView cells с разными outlets (segment, вкл/выкл, slider)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone, uitableview

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать TableView, в которой строки имеют элементы настроек (слайдер, сегмент или вкл/выкл элемент) и каждая строка - разный элемент? это будет меню настроек

Comment: в каждую ячейку поставить элемент настроек

Comment: Имеет смысл посмотреть: https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm , https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka , https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms .

Answer (score 2):

Используй uitableviewcontroller со статичными ячейками(Изображение ниже). В каждую ячейку просто перетяните необходимые элементы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Сделай для каждой ячейки подкласс от `UITableViewCell`, и добавь соответствующий xib. Аутлеты сделай как Property.